# Unity FPS style turning

Tags: unity, c#

I have this code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Control : MonoBehaviour {

public int speed;
public Transform tf;

// Use this for initialization
void Start () {

}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {
    if (Input.GetMouseButton(1))
    {
        tf.eulerAngles = tf.eulerAngles + new Vector3 (0, 
Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * speed, 0);
    }
}
}
```

I would like to know how to use this so that when I move my mouse and hole right click the character will turn but the mouse will not move from the center of the screen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to add mouse control to your game without having a cursor which might move off-screen, "capture" the mouse by calling [`Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.Locked;`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Cursor-lockState.html)

This will make the cursor disappear and fix it to the center of the screen so you can implement classic FPS mouselook controls without having to worrying about what happens if the cursor moves offscreen.

To restore the normal mouse cursor behavior, use `Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.None`. You can also use `Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.Confined` which restores the mouse cursor but doesn't allow the player to move it out of the game window.

There are two things you need to keep in mind:

- It will only work if the game window is the currently active window. So you should keep setting it every `Update`.
- It won't work at all if you build your game for the WebGL platform. Web browsers do not allow websites to take control of the user's mouse cursor. If you wonder why, just imagine the kind of evil the advertisers could do with that.